# Angular show image in Material Table Cell

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

I try to show an image in a cell of my Material table. Therefore I tried this code in my HTML File:

```xml
<ng-container matColumnDef="ImageUrl">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> imageUrl </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.imageUrl}} </mat-cell>
  <img [src]="imageUrl" />
</ng-container>
```

Unfortunately, nothing appears in my Table.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Give this a try:

```xml
<ng-container matColumnDef="imageUrl">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Image Url </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <img [src]="element.imageUrl" /> </td>
</ng-container>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-img-in-cells?file=app/table-basic-example.html) for your ref.

Comment: Just add a class or add this style to the `img` tag selector : `img { width: 30px; height: 30px; }` I've updated the same in the Sample StackBlitz. Please have a  look.

Comment: I would like to place the image in the table header, but moving the `<img [src]="mysource" />` to the mat-header-cell doesn't work, do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="imageUrl">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Image Url </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <img src="{{element.imageUrl}}" /> </td>
</ng-container>
```

...will also work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is going to work with one change. I would like to share the answer for those who would like to use `<mat-header-cell>` `<mat-cell>` instead of `<th><td>` in their table.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="ImageUrl">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> imageUrl </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <img [src]="element.imageUrl"/>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

[**Working Sample**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rcwbw9?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Very responsive answer